# Как сделать список с подкатегориями и одиночным выбором Android?

Tags: android, listview, recyclerview, multiple

Нужно реализовать список с подкатегориями, подкатегории имеют отступ. Выбор возможен одного элемента включая подкатегории. Как на скрине Category [image: Example]

Comment: Компонент ExpandableListView является расширенным вариантом компонента ListView. Основное отличие - разворачивающий список второго уровня.

Comment: Я новичок, был бы признателн увидеть это в коде

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  // названия компаний (групп)
  String[] groups = new String[] {"HTC", "Samsung", "LG"};

  // названия телефонов (элементов)
  String[] phonesHTC = new String[] {"Sensation", "Desire", "Wildfire", "Hero"};
  String[] phonesSams = new String[] {"Galaxy S II", "Galaxy Nexus", "Wave"};
  String[] phonesLG = new String[] {"Optimus", "Optimus Link", "Optimus Black", "Optimus One"};

  // коллекция для групп
  ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupData;

  // коллекция для элементов одной группы
  ArrayList<Map<String, String>> childDataItem;

  // общая коллекция для коллекций элементов
  ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> childData;
  // в итоге получится childData = ArrayList<childDataItem>

  // список атрибутов группы или элемента
  Map<String, String> m;

  ExpandableListView elvMain;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // заполняем коллекцию групп из массива с названиями групп
        groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String group : groups) {
          // заполняем список атрибутов для каждой группы
          m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("groupName", group); // имя компании
            groupData.add(m);  
        }

        // список атрибутов групп для чтения
        String groupFrom[] = new String[] {"groupName"};
        // список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены атрибуты групп
        int groupTo[] = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};


        // создаем коллекцию для коллекций элементов 
        childData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>(); 

        // создаем коллекцию элементов для первой группы
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        // заполняем список атрибутов для каждого элемента
        for (String phone : phonesHTC) {
          m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone); // название телефона
            childDataItem.add(m);  
        }
        // добавляем в коллекцию коллекций
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        // создаем коллекцию элементов для второй группы        
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone : phonesSams) {
          m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);  
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        // создаем коллекцию элементов для третьей группы        
        childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String phone : phonesLG) {
          m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("phoneName", phone);
            childDataItem.add(m);  
        }
        childData.add(childDataItem);

        // список атрибутов элементов для чтения
        String childFrom[] = new String[] {"phoneName"};
        // список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены атрибуты элементов
        int childTo[] = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};

        SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            groupData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            groupFrom,
            groupTo,
            childData,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            childFrom,
            childTo);

        elvMain = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elvMain);
        elvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Источник [startandroid.ru](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/86-urok-45-spisok-derevo-expandablelistview.html)

Этот код, поможет вам, приблизиться к требуемому. Важно понять код, если вы его хотите кастомизировать.

Работает он просто, сначала создается *новый объект коллекции* который будет содержать имя производителя **HTC** следом, создается новый объект коллекции для *моделей*, и туда забрасывает все модели из этого `String[] phonesHTC = \*...*/` массива и всё это помещается в `childData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>();` С остальными производителями происходит всё также, то есть создаются новые объекты.

**Если вам ответ помог**, оцените его. Есть вопросы, пишите.

Comment: Я видел эту реализацию. Спасибо, суть понятна, но это несколько другое чем на кратинке. Нужно именно как тут.. В тонкостях я запутался.

Comment: Ищите готовое решение на github, здесь нечем не могу помочь.